# How to pass an empty value to DatePicker and avoid input blocking?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I set up initial value for the DatePicker as null it's blocking keyboard input. How to avoid it?
Sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/embed/silly-black-y0dn7

```
function KeyboardDatePicker(props) {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(null);

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
      <DatePicker
        keyboard
        clearable
        label="Masked input"
        format="DD.MM.YYYY"
        mask={value =>
          value
            ? [/\d/, /\d/, ".", /\d/, /\d/, ".", /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
            : []
        }
        value={moment(selectedDate)}
        onChange={date => {
          handleDateChange(date);
        }}
        disableOpenOnEnter
        animateYearScrolling={false}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have made some changes in value prop https://codesandbox.io/embed/silly-black-y0dn7 is this something you're looking for  @fetchenko
?

Comment: input is still blocked, I can't enter a new value using keyboard

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try starting with a valid date object instead of null like this

```
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());
```

Or, if you'd prefer to start with a blank date, this should work:

```
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(null);
...
        value={selectedDate ? moment(selectedDate) : null}
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass an empty value? new Date() - fills filed with current date

Comment: If I use the second option it behaves as I've never provide initial value in the first place, and it raises warn 'A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled.' after user actually does select a date

Comment: regarding material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker V.3.2.9: null defaults to a blank and undefined defaults to the current date

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(null);
...
value={selectedDate ? moment(selectedDate) : null}
```

AND add this prop to the component:
`emptyLabel="put your here placeholder"`